# How to get the 10 most recent questions with accepted answers based on a given tag?

Tags: support, api, questions

I am trying to figure out how to get the 10 most recent questions from the Stack Overflow site, that have been answered, based on a given tag (such as 'Java').

I looked at the documentation but I didn't get a lot of help from it. I see that the API has an 'ids' URI path that can be entered but what does this mean?

Comment: By "have been answered", most people mean that the question has an *accepted* answer.  Is that what you mean here?

Comment: That is indeed what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use either:

- [/search/advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search)
  or
- [/search/excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search)

Then:

1. Set the `tagged` parameter to your tag.
2. Set the `accepted` parameter to `True`, if you want questions with *accepted* answers...
   OR
   Set `answers` to 1, if you want questions that have any old answer at all.
3. Set `pagesize` to 10.
4. Set `order` to `desc`.
5. Set `sort` to `creation`.

**For example,** the following query gets the latest ten questions, that have answers, in the *swank-clojure* tag:

```
/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=creation&accepted=True&tagged=swank-clojure
```

### Here is a [link to a live demo of that query.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=creation&accepted=True&tagged=swank-clojure&filter=!0Us_96RXD1tZDthgjR0.087A2&site=stackoverflow&run=true)